# Snowflake Handling of Stored Procedures

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My question is if an application has a backend as an Oracle Database in that case how snowflake will handle the Pl/SQL stored procedures and packages in which business logic has been implemented. Data can be migrated to snowflake, but how the stored procedures and packages will work. Do we need to rewrite the business logic in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You may choose to write the business logic in Stored procedure in Javascript, Sql, Snowflake scripting, Scala or Java.
It is entirely based on the requirements and how the SP has to be designed. More details on SP and the different types of it are here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures.html